# OR-tools VRP one vehicle with capacity constraint and multiple routes

Tags: python, or-tools

I am trying to solve a VRP using OR-tools in python. What i want to do is a vehicle that does multiple routes between a depo and pick-up destinations. It should pick items until its capacity is maxxed, go to depo and drop off and then continue with this until all items are picked.

I have searched the web and couldn't find anything. so i tried to combine the examples on OR-tools VRP without luck. So i wonder if there are any similar projects that can inspire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is a multi-trip Collect problem

- Each node can only be visited once, so if you want multiple trips , you'll need to duplicate the depot node to allow/simulate "unload" etc...
- Each unload node(s) should be optional so you should put them (one by one) in a disjunction so the solver don't have to visit them if not needed.

A good sample is [cvrp_reload.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py)